# How to make a table responsive? (stack columns)

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table with this structure.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I resize my browser window it looks this way:

```
| 1 | | 2 |
```

How can I make it responsive to make it look like this:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
```

I tried `display: block` but I guess I should use something difference.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of tables, as they are meant to represent _tabular data_ and tabular data should not be displayed in such a manner. If you are using it for any other purpose, well, **don't**. If you _have_ to theres always `display: inline-block;` but you'll have to apply it to a lot of elements (`table`, `tr`, `td`, `th)`.

Comment: @somethinghere, a table makes sense if you have the space to fit it. But I think that essentially turning each row into a card on narrower screens is a fair usage case.

Comment: @LukeStevenson Only use tables for tabular data, if it is just a layout decision, _do not use tables_, it will break the semantics of the web and accessibility. On top of that, it avoids confusion. If you have a list of cards arranged like a table, use a nested `ul` or `ol` and style the list items within them.

Comment: @somethinghere, unless the client limits the CSS you can use. Like emails. The unfortunate, and unavoidable, exception to the "tables for tables, not for layouts" rule.

Comment: @lukestevrnson I’ll give you that one, tbh. But only because thats what we’re stuck with :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this behaviour I do not think that tables are the way to go. Maybe take a look at how bootstrap handles their columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/

with that said. It can be done like this:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle where it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/90pvLy8t/

Comment: Can I do this with inline styling? As I know I cant use @media inline.

Answer (score 2):

you can add on css

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
  table,tr,td{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

But its not good idea for big table. So you can use data table https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
 #no-more-tables table, 
 #no-more-tables thead, 
 #no-more-tables tbody, 
 #no-more-tables th, 
 #no-more-tables td, 
 #no-more-tables tr { 
  display: block; 
 }
 
 /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
 #no-more-tables thead tr { 
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
 }
 
 #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
 #no-more-tables td { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%; 
  white-space: normal;
  text-align:left;
 }
 
 #no-more-tables td:before { 
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%; 
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:left;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 /*
 Label the data
 */
 #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                No more tables.
            </h1>
            <h3 class="text-center">
                Resize the browser screen to see how the table changes
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
          <thead class="cf">
           <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th class="numeric">Price</th>
            <th class="numeric">Change</th>
            <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
            <th class="numeric">Open</th>
            <th class="numeric">High</th>
            <th class="numeric">Low</th>
            <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAD</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ARDENT LEISURE GROUP</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">1.32%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.14</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.13</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">56,431</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AAX</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AUSENCO LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.04</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.99%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$4.01</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$4.05</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$4.00</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">90,641</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABC</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADELAIDE BRIGHTON LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.06</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.04%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$2.98</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.00</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$2.96</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">862,518</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ABACUS PROPERTY GROUP</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.91</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.92</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.93</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.90</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">595,701</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ABY</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADITYA BIRLA MINERALS LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">2.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.77</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.76</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">54,567</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ACR</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ACRUX LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.71</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.01</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.70</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.72</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.68</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">191,373</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">ADU</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ADAMUS RESOURCES LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">0.00</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.00%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$0.73</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$0.74</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$0.72</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">8,602,291</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGG</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ANGLOGOLD ASHANTI LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.22</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-2.74%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$7.82</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$7.81</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">148</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGK</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AGL ENERGY LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$13.82</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">0.14%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$13.83</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$13.67</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">846,403</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td data-title="Code">AGO</td>
            <td data-title="Company">ATLAS IRON LIMITED</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$3.17</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.02</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.47%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$3.11</td>
            <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$3.22</td>
            <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$3.10</td>
            <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">5,416,303</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="bg-success" style="padding:10px;margin-top:20px"><small><a href="http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#no-more-tables" target="_blank">Link</a> to original article</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9k6xL0dt/)

Reference : [Here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table)

Comment: This is really clever